# How to apply a function to every nth month in data frame?

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this:

```
Month   Amount
1/31/2014   793
2/28/2014   363
3/31/2014   857
4/30/2014   621
5/31/2014   948
6/30/2014   385
```

I would like to apply a function (x*0.5) to the third and sixth rows in this data frame. The results will overwrite the data currently in the data frame. So the end result would look like this:

```
Month   Amount
1/31/2014   793
2/28/2014   363
3/31/2014   428.5
4/30/2014   621
5/31/2014   948
6/30/2014   192.5
```

I've tried the rollapply() function, but that functions seems to start at the first row only without an option to force it to start at the third.

I really appreciate any help around this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your data.frame is named DT:

```
DT$Amount[c(3,6)] <- 0.5 * DT$Amount[c(3,6)]
```

If you have a lot of data, use data.table:

```
setDT(DT)
DT[
  month(as.Date(Month, format = "%m/%d/%Y")) %% 3 == 0, 
  Amount := 0.5 * Amount
]
```

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful. What if I wanted to only apply that function to March and June? That is, not by row, but instead by the month's name?

Comment: You could change that    month(...) %% 3 == 0    bit to    month(...) %in% c(3, 6)    . It's not the month's name but it works just as well. If you really wanted, you could use month.name[c(3,6)]..

Answer (score 0):

If the rows follow a pattern then `%%` can be used to select every `x` rows

```
df1$Amount[seq_len(nrow(df1)) %% 3 == 0] <- df1$Amount[seq_len(nrow(df1)) %% 3 == 0] * 0.5

      Month Amount
1 1/31/2014  793.0
2 2/28/2014  363.0
3 3/31/2014  428.5
4 4/30/2014  621.0
5 5/31/2014  948.0
6 6/30/2014  192.5
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative for detecting particular months in bigger datasets is using `month` from `lubridate()`

```
  month ammount
1 1/31/2014     793
2 2/28/2014     363
3 3/31/2014     857
4 4/30/2014     621
5 5/31/2014     948
6 6/30/2014     385

library(lubridate)

df %>% mutate(month = as.Date(month, "%m/%d/%Y"),
         date_month = month(month),
         new_ammount =  ifelse(date_month %in% c(3,6), ammount*0.5, ammount))
```

Which provides

```
     month ammount date_month new_ammount
1 2014-01-31     793          1       793.0
2 2014-02-28     363          2       363.0
3 2014-03-31     857          3       428.5
4 2014-04-30     621          4       621.0
5 2014-05-31     948          5       948.0
6 2014-06-30     385          6       192.5
```